# (sqlalchemy) Использование в bulk_update_mapping текущего времени БД

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Вопрос по sqlalchemy / postgresql

Делаю обновление записей через bulk_update_mappings.

В обновляемой таблице есть поле update_time с типом timestamp, в которое нужно вставлять текущее время.

Проблема в том, что есть два требования:

1. Для колонки нельзя установить default-значение.
2. Использовать надо именно время БД, то есть взять в клиентском коде datetime.now() и явно передать его - не вариант.

Если бы речь шла про сырой SQL, я бы просто использовал постгресовую функцию current_timestamp.

А вот как такое передать через алхимию в методе bulk_update_mappings ?

Answer (score 0):

Тайм-зона сервера известна?

Например, Europe/Moscow

Тогда строка времени вычисляется в три приёма: текущее время клиента в UTC -> текущее время в ТЗ сервера -> строчка для записи в БД.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

SRV_TZ = pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow")

utc_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) # datetime object with UTC TZ set
srv_time = utc_time.astimezone(SRV_TZ) # datetime object with MSK TZ

srv_time_str = srv_time.isoformat()
```

Я бы пошел таким путём.